# What is system/bin and system/xbin in android M?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, shell

I have few noob questions about the `system/bin` and `system/xbin` directory in Android M.

First, what is the file inside this two directories?

Next, in `system/bin`, the is some file looks like

```
-rwxr-xr-x root     shell      117136 2008-12-31 11:30 test-platform
lrwxr-xr-x root     shell             2008-12-31 11:30 time -> toybox
lrwxr-xr-x root     shell             2008-12-31 11:30 timeout -> toybox
lrwxr-xr-x root     shell             2008-12-31 11:30 umount -> toybox
```

I know toybox is the app like busybox, a collection of unix command, but what does the `->` means here?

Third, I am getting the error `/system/bin/sh: busybox: not found`, is this shows that busybox is not installed? I thought toybox already serving the same function as busybox?

Appreciate if anyone could clarify my questions, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. the `->` indicates this is a symbolic link. That's how Busybox (and similar apps) work, so other processes can refer to them by the "full fledged name" of the component they need to call.
2. There are different "busyboxes". The original Busybox has a binary called `busybox` – yours has a binary called `toybox`. That won't matter if one of those symlinks is addressed – but if some process tries to call `busybox` directly, it of course cannot find it if it's not there. To work around that, you could create another symlink to `toybox`: `ln -s /system/bin/toybox /system/bin/busybox` (in order to do that you need root and mount the `/system` partition read/write).

Comment: still fail to get `busybox` after symbolic link created. `/system/bin/sh: busybox: not found`

Comment: Where do you get those errors? What are you doing? Hard to tell how to fix what one doesn't know existing. You might rather need to fix the script causing those errors. Btw: If busybox is still "not found", did creating the link succeed at all? What does `which busybox` give, and what does `ls -l /system/bin | grep busybox` show?

Comment: I have tried `which busybox` which give nothing on terminal. `ls -l /system/bin | grep busybox` return `busybox -> system/bin/toybox` which means symbolic link created successfully? TQ

Comment: That's strange. Yes, it seems the symlink was created correctly but `busybox` is still not found. Can you verify that `/system/bin` is in your `PATH` (`echo $PATH`)? I guess the easiest way would be installing a proper `busybox` on your device (just checked: mine has both `toybox` AND `busybox` as well). Due to the nature of both working (they check how they're called to decide what they're to do – so Toybox might get confused when called as `busybox`).

Comment: I'm 6 years late to the party, but the reason I believe it was not working is because from the output of `ls -l` from @hellojoshhhy they forgot to put the first `/` when creating the symbolic link, so it's a relative link instead of absolute, so it's trying to look for a directory named `system` in the current directory.